# Emulator not working for resolution 1920 * 1080 as of Samsung S4 and Sony Xperia Z

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am Working on a project in which i need to create design for new resolution i.e 1920 * 1080.

But,i do not have an android phone of this resolution. So, i decided to check over emulator.
and in Starting, i create a new device with this resolution and it always show black screen and then after i installed new Sony sdk of xperia z, it didn't work.

when i explored websites then i got to know that it is full hd emulator resolution and does not work without graphics card.

And now, i am using Graphics card in my pc and there is some success in starting of emulator that before it only shows black screen but now it shows that it is starting by displaying android logo but still doesn't move further and some times it becomes totally white and some time not responding.

These are my configuration of my pc.

1. Processor-core2 duo(2.53 GHz).
2. Processor model no-E7200.
3. ram-3 Gb.
4. Graphics card- NVIDIA GeForce 210.

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some known issues with Ram size of AVD emulator being greater than 750MB in windows, check for this, it might create problems with your hd settings as 750MB or less ram for emulator might fall short.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps, before you create your emulator for Sony Xperia Z..

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/#installsdk

http://developer.sonymobile.com/how-to-install-the-sony-add-on-sdk-manually/

I have Created emulator successfully for Sony Xperia Z1 Model..

Please Read the above link document to to bottom carefully..
It contains complete solutions for Create EMulator for Sony Xperia Z Model..

Important Mistakes occured while Creating this High Resution Emulator..Read it..

I get the “Failed to allocate memory: 8″ error when I tried to start the Sony Add-on SDK emulator. What is wrong?
The default emulator configuration may require more memory than what is currently available in your computer. Reduce the RAM setting for the AVD to 512MB and restart the emulator.

I tried to launch the Xperia™ Z and Xperia™ Tablet Z emulator but I only get a black screen? What is wrong?
For emulators with high display resolutions, the GPU emulation feature of the Android SDK should be used to aid in the screen transitions. Please make sure that your computer is equipped with a working GPU, and that the checkbox for Use Host GPU in the AVD settings is checked.

Thanks..

Comment: hmm .. sounds like a follow-up question to me, is it?